# Problem creating a dynamic reverse lookup function

Tags: excel, vba

Background:

- multiple sheets filled with employees and possible training sessions
- "x" marked trainings are completed by the employee

Goal:

- sheet where I can paste the employee number and get a list of completed Trainings for each year

I'm not using VBA very often but I tried my best with this one.

I tired to build a function which (theoretically) should use the given parameters to get the names of the trainings. I can't get it runinng without giving me `#VAULE!`.

```
Function TS(PersNum As String, Numbers As Range, Trainings As Range, Optional SearchRow As Range)
    TrainRow = Trainings.Rows(1)        'all trainings are listed in this row
    TS = ""

    For Each cell In Numbers            'search in column for the employee number            
        If cell.Value = PersNum Then     
            cell.Row = SearchRow         'if match -> set row of the cell as range for SearchRow  
        Else
            Resume Next
        End If
    Next cell

    For Each cell2 In SearchRow         'search every cell in SearchRow for "x"   
        If cell2.Value = "x" Then
            TS = TS & Cells(TrainRow, cell2.Cloumn).Value & Chr(10) 'match -> return trainingsname with a carriage return
        Else
            Resume Next
        End If
    Next cell2
End Function
```

I expected it to search for the given number in the column given with the parameter. As soon as it founds a match it should paste the row of the column to the "SearchRow" variable and exit the search. Afterwards it should look through the row and give me the Title of every Column marked with an "x" as text in the cell the function is located.

Example:

[image: Workbook and search layout]

This is the worksheet I'm working on, a cell where I enter the employee Number and a cell with this function: `=TS(C2;'2019'!B:B;'2019'!3:3)`
For every year I want the list to be collected.

The Data I want to collect looks like this:

[image: Test Data]

Every column header marked with an "x" in the row of the employee should be added to the list. 
In the end I would like to have a listing under the year cell in the search sheet with an wordwrap after each training

Comment: First: have a look at [mcve]. Without the formula (how you call the function) and sample data (input/outpit) it is no full example (which we need to help you properly). • Second: Debug your code. Go through it step by step using F8 (use a test sub to call this function or place a `Stop` statement as first line in the function to get into debugging).

Comment: I hope this helps a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following:

- Read the data into arrays for faster lookup and processing
- Use the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.WorksheetFunction.Match) to get the row number of the matching personal id
- Loop through the columns of the matched row to find the `x` and if we find one add its header (from row 1) to the list.

  Note that the `x` is case sensitive if you want to allow both lower case `x` and upper case `X` then use `If lCase(Data(FoundRow, iCol)) = "x" Then` instead.
- In the last step we remove the line break `vbLf` in the very end (which is not needed).

So this is what you end up with:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetHeaderList(PersonalID As String, DataRange As Range) As String
    Dim Data() As Variant
    Data = DataRange.Value 'read data into array for fast access

    Dim LookupColumn() As Variant
    LookupColumn = DataRange.Columns(1).Value 'read first column into array for fast access

    'find row of personal id
    Dim FoundRow As Double
    On Error Resume Next 'next line errors if nothing matched
    FoundRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(PersonalID, LookupColumn, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0 'don't forget to re-activate error reporting!

    'collect header data
    If FoundRow > 0 Then 'FoundRow is 0 if nothing matched
        Dim iCol As Long
        For iCol = 2 To UBound(Data, 2)
            If Data(FoundRow, iCol) = "x" Then 'x is case sensitive
                GetHeaderList = GetHeaderList & Data(1, iCol) & vbLf
            End If
        Next iCol
    End If

    'remove last vbLf
    If Right$(GetHeaderList, 1) = vbLf Then
        GetHeaderList = Left$(GetHeaderList, Len(GetHeaderList) - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

To get the following result with this formula in C5:

```
=GetHeaderList(C2;'2019'!B3:G8) 'German Excel
=GetHeaderList(C2,'2019'!B3:G8) 'English Excel
```

Note that the complete data range is given in the formula including headers and lookup column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly with the Test sheet! 

But I've a small problem using the code for the productive workbook. The code runs through without an error but the cells stay empty.

Is there a maximum rangesize for the Match function? I can't figure out any other problem.

Comment: If they stay empty it did not match. I don't know of any limit. Make sure that the range you give in the formula has the personal id as first column and the headers as first row. Hard to say what is going wrong without seeing the data.

Comment: Don't ask me why but after reentering every ID Number manually the function works just fine. So thanks a lot it's working perfectly!

Comment: @J4YR4R Either a hidden space or number formatted as text (or other way round) could have caused this.